# Difference between ArrayList<>() and ArrayList<>(){}

Tags: java

What is the difference between those two. Why does the latter create a new serializable class?

```
new ArrayList<Clazz>()
```

creates a new empty `ArrayList`

```
new ArrayList<Clazz>(){}
```

Eclipse shows: `The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first example, you're creating an `ArrayList`  instance. In the latter you're creating instance of an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`. Usually you would override one or more methods in the subclass, <strike>otherwise there's not much point in creating such.</strike> As John Skeet points out, there is one hacky reason to create an anonymous subclass of a generic type, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790039/difference-between-arraylist-and-arraylist/7790098#7790098).

The Eclipse warns that, in order to adhere to the `Serializable` specifications (`ArrayList` is `Serializable`, so all its subclasses are too), you should define an unique `serialVersionUID` in the subclass from which the deserialization process can  ensure that the class definition has not changed significantly since it was serialized (significantly == you yourself have decided that the new definition is incompatible with the old one, so you can express the fact by changing the `serialVersionUID`). If you're never going to serialize the list, then the warning doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

As Joonas says, in the second example you're creating an anonymous inner class. However, there *is* a reason to do this even when you're not overriding any methods etc: it allows you to determine the element type of the `ArrayList` at execution time - because the superclass of the anonymous inner class is `ArrayList<Clazz>` rather than just `ArrayList`.

This is how type literals work in Guice. It's a bit of an ugly hack, but it gets the job done...

Comment: How does it allow him to determine the element type at runtime?

Comment: @LouisRhys: If you call `getClass()` on the instance, it will give the anonymous class. If you then call `getGenericSuperclass()` that `Type` will have the appropriate information.